# Add a indigo theme to my bootstrap html file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to change the current default theme to indigo theme of bootstrap. What changes I need to make it so in the below code?

I have added `$primary: colorname` but that didnt make any difference

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
$primary: rebeccapurple;
$danger: #dd0000;
$success: lime;
$warning: orange;
$info: aqua;

$body-bg: #f3f3f0;

@import "bootstrap";

</style>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" class="search">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.."  class="search">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
    
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.."  class="search">
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
            
    
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script>
$(function(){

  $('.dropdown-item').click(function(e){
var value = $(this).data('value');
var textElement = $(this).parent().parent().prev()
textElement = textElement.val(textElement.val() + value);
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
textElement.focus()
  });
  
});


$(".search").keyup(function(){
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = $(this).get(0);
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = $(this).parent().get(0);

  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  a[i].style.display = "";
} else {
  a[i].style.display = "none";
}
  }
});

(function() {
var disable = false;
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
        disable = true;
        console.log("inside1")
    })
    .on('focus', function() {
        if (!disable) {
            $(this).dropdown('toggle');            console.log("inside2")
        }
    })
    .on('mouseup touchend',function() {
        disable = false;console.log("inside3")
    })
})()

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stick SASS syntax into a `<style>` element.

You appear to have skipped over the [introduction to using SASS with Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/) which says:

> Whenever possible, avoid modifying Bootstrap’s core files. For Sass, that means **creating your own stylesheet that imports Bootstrap** so you can modify and extend it.

It goes on to give examples.

You'll then use the CSS you generate from the SASS **instead** of the CSS hosted on the CDN.

You can find an [introduction to SASS](https://sass-lang.com/guide) on the SASS website.

Comment: My page is a single page and I cannot host any other files, How and where do I modify the code ?

Comment: You download [the source files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/#source-files) to your workstation, [import them into your stylesheet](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/#importing), then compile them to CSS with SASS, then publish the CSS … somewhere. If you only have hosting for a single HTML file then you could shove the whole thing between `<style>` and `</style>`.